# AbstractUIPlugin causing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, noclassdeffounderror

I am writing an Eclipse plugin that supports automated testing like JUnit. I have a Launch Configuration Delegate that launches my Main class, which will run the tests on the class the user provides.

I want to programmatically show a custom View from my Eclipse plugin when I launch it with my Launch Configuration Delegate. I keep getting a NoClassDefFoundError for the AbstractUIPlugin class when I try to launch it even though I have included both org.eclipse.ui and org.eclipse.core.runtime in my plugin dependencies.

**Stack Trace**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/plugin/AbstractUIPlugin
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at eoo.thefamilycoder.specj.internal.launching.delegate.SpecJMain.main(SpecJMain.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: SpecJ
Bundle-SymbolicName: eoo.thefamilycoder.specj;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.alpha
Bundle-Activator: eoo.thefamilycoder.specj.internal.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui;bundle-version="3.105.0",
 org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="3.9.0",
 org.eclipse.jdt.launching;bundle-version="3.7.0",
 org.eclipse.debug.core;bundle-version="3.8.0",
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.9.1",
 org.eclipse.debug.ui;bundle-version="3.9.0",
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui;bundle-version="3.9.1",
 org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui;bundle-version="3.6.200"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

**Main class**

```
import eoo.thefamilycoder.specj.internal.Activator;

public class SpecJMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Activator.getDefault().showView();
    }

}
```

### What is causing the error, and how can I fix it?

**Edit:** Adding launch code

**Launch Configuration Delegate**

```
public class SpecJLaunchConfigurationDelegate extends AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate {

    private static final int UNITS_OF_WORK = 4;

    @Override
    public void launch(final ILaunchConfiguration configuration, final String mode, final ILaunch launch,
            final IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
        final IProgressMonitor pm = monitor != null ? monitor : new NullProgressMonitor();

        pm.beginTask(configuration.getName(), UNITS_OF_WORK);
        if (pm.isCanceled()) return;

        try {
            preLaunchCheck(configuration, mode, pm);
            if (pm.isCanceled()) return;

            final VMRunnerConfiguration runConfig =
                new VMRunnerConfigurationFactory().create(configuration, monitor, this);
            if (pm.isCanceled()) return;

            getVMRunner(configuration, mode).run(runConfig, launch, pm);
            if (pm.isCanceled()) return;
        } finally {
            pm.done();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getClasspath(ILaunchConfiguration configuration) throws CoreException {
        final String[] initialClasspath = super.getClasspath(configuration);

        final String pluginClasspath = new SpecJClasspathLocator().getClasspath();
        System.out.println(pluginClasspath);
        if (pluginClasspath == null) return initialClasspath;

        final String[] classpath = new String[initialClasspath.length + 1];
        classpath[0] = pluginClasspath;
        System.arraycopy(initialClasspath, 0, classpath, 1, initialClasspath.length);

        return classpath;
    }

}
```

**VMRunnerConfigurationFactory**

```
public class VMRunnerConfigurationFactory {

    public VMRunnerConfiguration create(final ILaunchConfiguration configuration, final IProgressMonitor monitor,
            final AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate delegate) throws CoreException {
        final ExecutionArguments execArgs = new ExecutionArguments(delegate.getVMArguments(configuration), "");

            // Activator.MAIN_TYPE_NAME is the main class above
        final VMRunnerConfiguration runConfig = new VMRunnerConfiguration(Activator.MAIN_TYPE_NAME,
            delegate.getClasspath(configuration));
        runConfig.setBootClassPath(delegate.getBootpath(configuration));
        runConfig.setEnvironment(delegate.getEnvironment(configuration));
        runConfig.setProgramArguments(new ProgramArgumentsFactory().create(configuration, monitor));
        runConfig.setVMArguments(execArgs.getVMArgumentsArray());
        runConfig.setVMSpecificAttributesMap(delegate.getVMSpecificAttributesMap(configuration));
        runConfig.setWorkingDirectory(getWorkingDirectoryName(delegate.verifyWorkingDirectory(configuration)));
        return runConfig;
    }

    private String getWorkingDirectoryName(final File workingDir) throws CoreException {
        return workingDir != null ? workingDir.getAbsolutePath() : null;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do? Do you just want to run a plugin (which has to be inside an Eclipse instance)?

Comment: @greg-449 I have edited my question with a summary of the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

`AbstractUIPlugin` is in the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` plug-in so you need that in your dependencies.

Edit.

Just noticed you are using a `main` method - this an Eclipse plugin you can't run this is as a normal Java program. You must either run it in an existing Eclipse RCP or create a RCP.

Edit 2

Your launch does nothing to properly initialize Eclipse to run a plugin. You must start an Eclipse app through the `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main` entry point (normally via the `eclipse` executable). You must specify an application or product to run (like in the `Run Configuration` for an `Eclipse Application`).

Comment: It doesn't work. I imported org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin, which should be covered under the org.eclipse.ui dependency. Is there another one in org.eclipse.ui.workbench that I should import instead?

Comment: Update with note about not being about to use main.

Comment: I'm using a custom launch configuration delegate to launch the main program. I launch the plugin itself with Eclipse Application.

Comment: We'll you better show us that launch code, because I don't see how this could set things up properly for a plugin to run

Comment: More comments in answer

Comment: How do I do that? Can you give an example?